# Old Lambda function is the one being triggered after updating existing API Gateway with new Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Name of old Lambda function : OldLambda

Name of new Lambda function : OldLambda-810

The new lambda function was made from scratch but meant to be an exact copy of the old Lambda with just a minor change. Both triggered via API Gateway.

Went to AWS API Gateway, found the Endpoint, edited 'Lambda Function' from OldLambda to OldLambda-810.  This change is reflected correctly in the AWS Lambda functions.

I would like to test the new Lambda by triggering it through the real application but no new CloudWatch log were created with the new Lambda function. Instead, there are new logs for OldLambda.

When I trigger the new Lambda through a Lambda test event, the logs are created.

Comment: Did you re-deploy the API stage?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : Redeploying the API Stage worked!! Thank you so much. 
For anyone else wondering Go to Api Gateway > Resource > Actions > Deploy API > Select any existing stage from the Deploy stage drop-down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API changes made in the API Gateway console typically don't take effect immediately.  This is admittedly not always intuitive, but you need to "deploy" the API to a stage in order to push your changes live.  Think of a "stage" as a pointer to a snapshot of configured behavior as it existed when the API rules were last deployed.

> **Important**
>
> Every time you update an API, which includes modification of routes, methods, integrations, authorizers, and anything else other than stage settings, you must redeploy the API to an existing stage or to a new stage.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api.html